# D Module Name Being Printed by Module Destructor

Tags: d, tango, d1

I've recently started learning D version 1, using the Tango library. I decided to write a small class `Dout` that wraps `tango.io.Stdout`, except it overrides `opShl` to better match C++'s `<<` style output. My implementation is like so:

```
// dout.d
module do.Dout;

import tango.io.Stdout;

class Dout
{
    public static Dout opShl(T) (T arg)
    {
        stdout(arg);
        return new Dout;
    }

    public static Dout newline()
    {
        stdout.newline;
        return new Dout;
    }
}
```

And in main, I make a simple call to Dout.opShl(), like so.

```
// main.d
import do.Dout;
import tango.io.Console;

int main(char[][] argv)
{
    Dout << "Hello" << " world!" << Dout.newline;
    Cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This works, but after pressing enter and exiting main, the text "do.Dout.Dout" is printed. After stepping through the code, I found that this text is printed at the assembly instruction:

`00406B5C  call __moduleDtor (40626Ch)`

In which do.Dout's destructor is being called.

My question is, why is the module name being printed upon exiting main, and what can I do to stop this behaviour?

Comment: off-topic, but still related - D1 is not going to be developed further. D version 2 is the future, and I wholeheartedly recommend you chose that version instead, if you want to learn D. There is a project to port Tango to D2, so I guess the time you spend learning Tango won't be a waste of time.

Comment: True; I decided to go with D1 specifically because I want to use Tango over Phobos; coming from a C++ background, I deemed that Tango would be a closer match. Once D2 is stable, I will definitely be switching over.

Comment: While this may be fun, do not overload the shift left operator for standard out. Also D1 is going to be developed until 2013.

Comment: @he_the_great I realize that this is a bad thing to do in actual code. I was just playing around, getting a feel for D's operator overloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason "do.Dout.Dout" is printed is because `Dout << Dout.newline;` prints a new line (in the `newline` property call) and then attempts to print a human readable string of a `Dout` object (after it is passed to `opShl!Dout()`)

and you only see it during destruction because then the output is flushed ;)

you should have done

```
__gshared Doutclass Dout = new Doutclass;

class Doutclass
{
    public Dout opShl(T) (T arg)
    {
        static if(T == NLine){
            stdout.newline;//if nl is passed do newline
        }else{
            stdout(arg);
        }
        return this;
    }

    struct NLine{}//this might need a dummy field to stop compiler complaints
    public static NLine newline()
    {
        return NLine();
    }
}
```

which is closer to the C style (Dout is an global object and *doesn't get recreated* each call, newline is a special struct that flushed the output besides adding a newline to it)

Comment: I can't seem to get __gshared to work using DMD 1.0. Is this a 2.0 feature? The documentation is absent on the official website.

Comment: yeah it's a D2 feature check http://www.d-programming-language.org/migrate-to-shared.html you can do without __gshared